# Read a single line from stdin to a string in one line of code

Tags: rust

I know that I can read one line and convert it to number in one line, i.e.

```
let lines: u32 = io::stdin().read_line().ok().unwrap().trim().parse().unwrap();
```

How to do the same without parse and in one line? Right now I do this:

```
let line_u = io::stdin().read_line().ok().unwrap();
let line_t = line_u.as_slice().trim();
```

**Edit**: Explanation what's going on here:

```
pub fn stdin() -> StdinReader
fn read_line(&mut self) -> IoResult<String> // method of StdinReader
type IoResult<T> = Result<T, IoError>;
fn ok(self) -> Option<T>                    // method of Result
fn unwrap(self) -> T                        // method of Option
fn trim(&self) -> &str                      // method of str from trait StrExt
fn to_string(?) -> String // I don't know where is this located in documentation
```

We can use trim on String, because String is a str decoreated with pointer, an owned string.

[parse()](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.StrExt.html#tymethod.parse),
[stdin()](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/stdio/fn.stdin.html),
[read_line()](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/stdio/struct.StdinReader.html#method.read_line), 
[IoResult](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/type.IoResult.html), 
[ok()](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.ok), 
[unwrap()](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap),
[trim()](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/str/trait.StrExt.html#tymethod.trim),
[str](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/str/index.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`trim()` returns an `&str` view of the `String` returned by `unwrap()`.  You can't store this object because the owning `String` will no longer exist at the end of the statement. So just use `to_string()` to convert the `&str` back to a `String`.

```
let line = io::stdin().read_line().ok().unwrap().trim().to_string();
```