# How to find in documentation that to_string is available for &str?

Tags: rust

I was trying to understand what's going on when [reading a line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27972686/read-only-one-line-to-string-in-one-line-of-code), but I couldn't find that there is a method `to_string` in the documentation for [str](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/str/index.html), even though I know it's there.

Comment: I would think that the [ToString](http://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0-alpha/std/string/trait.ToString.html) trait should be listed under the Traits of `str`, but (as I'm sure you've noticed) it's not there. I'm not sure if this was a slip, or if the docs are generated automatically and there is a bug in that process. The place *I* learned about it is from [the book](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/).

Comment: There is no direct link between `str` and `ToString::to_string` in the docs -- because `ToString` has a "blanket" implementation "for all T so that T: String" for a different trait, the formatting trait `String`.

Comment: @user139873: So it's a documentation generation issue, the documentation would also need to take blanket implementations into account.

Comment: Absolutely. It's always been that the tools don't quite keep up with the language. Eventually it will get there I think.

Comment: Note that the `String` trait has been renamed to [`Display`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Display.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct link between [`&str`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html) and [`ToString::to_string`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/trait.ToString.html#tymethod.to_string) in the docs because `ToString` has a *blanket implementation*:

```
impl<T> ToString for T where T: Display, T: ?Sized
```

This means that `ToString` is implemented for any item that implements [`Display`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Display.html). `&str` does implement `Display`.

(Moved from [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3616050/user139873)).