# How to convert a SocketAddr to a String in Rust?

Tags: sockets, rust, type-conversion

How can I convert a `SocketAddr` into a `String`? I know [how to do the conversion the other way round](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28255861/155423).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You convert it to a string by calling [`to_string`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/trait.ToString.html#tymethod.to_string):

```
fn example(addr: &SocketAddr) -> String {
    addr.to_string()
}
```

See also:

- [How to find in documentation that to_string is available for &str?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27974327/155423)
- [Should I implement Display or ToString to render a type as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27769681/155423)